# Avoid nested loops when iterating over Pandas DataFrame with condition over items

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, nested

The folllowing code iterates through each member of a Pandas DataFrame, asking whether the item's absolute value is >= 0.5 and, if yes, appends its value to a list together with corresponding column and row names:

```
record = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        if abs(df.iloc[i, j]) >= 0.5:
            record.append([df.columns[j], df.index[i], df.iloc[i, j]])
```

Of course it can take some time depending on the dataframe size, as it is quite inefficient to do those nested loops...

Is there a better, quicker, more pythonic way to do this?

Sample input:

```
      colA  colB  colC  colD
row1  -0.7   0.3   0.6  -0.2
row2   0.4  -0.3   0.8  -0.9
```

Sample output:

```
[['colA', 'row1', -0.7],
 ['colC', 'row1', 0.6],
 ['colC', 'row2', 0.8],
 ['colD', 'row2', -0.9]]
```

Comment: You should add a small example dataset which can be copied by us. And based on that example, what your expected output is.

Comment: @Erfan, thanks for the reminder. Just did that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way `mask` the value of whole df then `stack`

```
df.where(df.abs()>0.5).stack().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use numpy. Transform the values of the pandas Data frame to numpy with:

```
import numpy as np

A = df.to_numpy()
```

For having data I generate them first with random and then I pick out the data greater than 0.5:

```
A = np.random.randn(3, 6)
B = A[A>=0.5]
B

array([0.87244799, 1.35438111, 1.18743473, 0.65015131, 0.71182848,
       0.85945553, 2.02416415, 0.53008776])
```

Comment: The problem is: (1) only gets items >= 0.5 (and not items whose absolute values are >= 0.5), but I believe this can be fixed by changing "A >= 0.5" to "np.abs(A) >= 0.5"; and (2) it doesn't get column and row names.

Comment: Point (2) is easy: when we have the correct output in numpy we can cast it into the pandas data frame back again.

Comment: In the mean time you have obviously added a prefered output to the question, which is fine, then it is very different to what I've got out from the question without it. (I dont know, where the down vote is from. But at least we try to work with and for you)